# sql query customer who ordered more than 15 times

Tags: mysql

how to get list of customers who ordered more than 15times.
i have customerId , orderId , orderValue , orderDate.

I tried

```
select *  from customertable Group By customerId having count (*) > 15
```

Comment: If you're still struggling, pretend it's more than 3 times, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

You can try below -

```
select customerid
  from customertable 
  Group By customerId having count (distinct orderid) >= 15
```

Comment: If orderid isn't unique, then we have bigger problems!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customerid, COUNT(*) counter
FROM customertable 
GROUP BY customerId HAVING counter >= 15
```